# How to create custom scroll icon inside the Material-UI scrolling Tabs

Tags: reactjs, tabs, material-ui

I am using [Scrollable tabs](https://material-ui.com/components/tabs/#scrollable-tabs) from Material-UI. How do I change the `svg` icon of the scroll arrows?

I see there is [TabScrollButton](https://material-ui.com/api/tab-scroll-button/) component you can use. So do I have to create one for the left and right arrow?

And in Tabs component you can pass a prop `ScrollButtonComponent`. But how do I have to use it?

I tried below but it isn't working yet:

```
import Tab from '@material-ui/core/Tab';
import Tabs from '@material-ui/core/Tabs';
import TabScrollButton from '@material-ui/core/TabScrollButton';

import { CloseIcon } from 'app/components/atoms/icons';

const MyCarousel = ({ value }: Props) => {
  const selectedItem = value;

  const scrollButton = () => {
    return (
      <div>
        <TabScrollButton orientation="horizontal" direction="right">
          {CloseIcon}
        </TabScrollButton>
      </div>
    );
  };

  return (
    <div css={styles.root}>
      <Tabs
        value={value}
        indicatorColor="primary"
        variant="scrollable"
        scrollButtons="auto"
        aria-label="scrollable auto tabs example"
        ScrollButtonComponent={scrollButton}
      >
        <Tab label="Item One" />
        <Tab label="Item Two" />
        <Tab label="Item Three" />
        <Tab label="Item 4" />
        <Tab label="Item 5" />
        <Tab label="Item 6" />
        <Tab label="Item 7" />
        <Tab label="Item 8" />
        <Tab label="Item 9" />
      </Tabs>
    </div>
  );
};

export default MyCarousel;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're close. `TabScrollButton` is the [default props](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/d520cfcbe9a8bdb3dfb12224a9183fbc4814e235/packages/material-ui/src/Tabs/Tabs.js#L99) of `ScrollButtonComponent`. Unfortunately, `TabScrollButton` doesn't provide any props to override the back/forward icons. So you have to create one yourself.

This is the definition of [`TabScrollButton`](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/d520cfcbe9a8bdb3dfb12224a9183fbc4814e235/packages/material-ui/src/TabScrollButton/TabScrollButton.js#L62). What you want to do is to copy the definition, remove unnecessary parts and add your own icons instead. Below is an example:

```js
import ButtonBase from "@material-ui/core/ButtonBase";
import ArrowBackIcon from "@material-ui/icons/ArrowBack";
import ArrowForwardIcon from "@material-ui/icons/ArrowForward";

const MyTabScrollButton = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  const { direction, ...other } = props;

  return (
    <ButtonBase
      component="div"
      ref={ref}
      style={{ opacity: other.disabled ? 0 : 1 }}
      {...other}
    >
      {direction === "left" ? (
        <ArrowBackIcon fontSize="small" />
      ) : (
        <ArrowForwardIcon fontSize="small" />
      )}
    </ButtonBase>
  );
});
```

```js
<Tabs
  {...tabsProps}
  variant="scrollable"
  scrollButtons="auto"
  ScrollButtonComponent={MyTabScrollButton}
>
  {...}
</Tabs>
```

### Live Demo

[image: Edit 66982823/how-create-custom-scroll-icon-inside-the-material-ui-scrolling-tabs]

Comment: ok thanks! I created [this example](https://codesandbox.io/s/jovial-feynman-lvl2z?) to fit my needs. Do you know why it isn't scrolling yet? Also I want to auto-hide the buttons... Like when you use the original scroll tabs setup.

Comment: @meez you need to [spread](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/d520cfcbe9a8bdb3dfb12224a9183fbc4814e235/packages/material-ui/src/TabScrollButton/TabScrollButton.js#L79) `other` props on the root component

Comment: @meez you can use `disabled` props to toggle the button visibility. I've updated the answer for you.

Comment: thanks, due to our ESLint setup I can't use props spreading. What do I have to do, which prop am I missing `orientation` prop? On `ButtonBase` I can't add `orientation` prop

Comment: you can log the other props: `console.log(other)` and pass each of them manually to see which one works. @meez

Comment: @meez `handleStartScrollClick` is a value, like when you set `onClick = 5`, `5` is the value and you can't pass `5` to the props because you don't know what the value is until you log it to the screen. What you need to do is passing `onClick` (the variable contains the value) like this: `<ButtonBase onClick={props.onClick} ...>`